# How to use strncpy_s in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, c11, tr24731

i am trying t use strncpy_s functionality  in my C++ program , 
but my code is unable to reach strncpy_s , due to macro defined , please let me know how to use strncpy_s in gcc , thanks in advance, 
my code is as below

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

 printf("\n\t Hello World ");
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
    set_constraint_handler_s(ignore_handler_s);
    char dst1[6], src1[100] = "hello";
    int r1 = strncpy_s(dst1, 6, src1, 100);      // writes 0 to r1, 6 characters to dst1
    printf("dst1 = \"%s\", r1 = %d\n", dst1,r1); // 'h','e','l','l','o','\0' to dst1

    char dst2[5], src2[7] = {'g','o','o','d','b','y','e'};
    int r2 = strncpy_s(dst2, 5, src2, 7);        // copy overflows the destination array
    printf("dst2 = \"%s\", r2 = %d\n", dst2,r2); // writes nonzero to r2,'\0' to dst2[0]

    char dst3[5];
    int r3 = strncpy_s(dst3, 5, src2, 4);        // writes 0 to r3, 5 characters to dst3
    printf("dst3 = \"%s\", r3 = %d\n", dst3,r3); // 'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', '\0' to dst3 
    printf("\n\t Bye bye!!");
#endif
}
```

and my code is not going inside the ifdef , is there any other way to use strncpy_s.

Comment: Why not actually use C++ and use `std::string`?

Comment: Are you on windows? strncpy_s is not provided by most platforms.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use C++? This looks like a C program.

Comment: I have copied the program  , from google as i cannot copy actual program. how can i this C ? to execute strncpy_s

Comment: You say "C++ program" but then you choose C tag. Please decide which language you are trying to use

Comment: Please help me in any language , either C or C++